# compare two arrays and take values ​from the first array not contained in the second array

Tags: javascript

I have this array with 3 of size

```
[
  'decdbaf8-db89-4d4b-973a-e8edab55927c',
  'c553c2f7-eff6-476e-b718-2814a7fa5435',
  '8717092f-5820-474b-9dd9-165e2649180f'
]
```

and this array with size equals 2:

```
[
  {
    id: 'c553c2f7-eff6-476e-b718-2814a7fa5435',
    name: 'test',
    codReference: '15422aa',
    category_id: '7a026a80-f3d2-462a-ad5d-598e9eabf693',
    created_at: 2020-10-29T22:23:35.928Z,
    updated_at: 2020-10-29T22:23:35.928Z,
    deleted_at: null
  },
  {
    id: 'decdbaf8-db89-4d4b-973a-e8edab55927c',
    name: 'test',
    codReference: '2',
    category_id: '7a026a80-f3d2-462a-ad5d-598e9eabf693',
    created_at: 2020-10-29T22:23:37.784Z,
    updated_at: 2020-10-29T22:23:37.784Z,
    deleted_at: null
  }
]
```

I know that if I were to get only one item that is not contained in the array, I would just use: indexOf (value)> -1;

but how can I compare the two arrays and get only the values ​​of the first array that are not contained in the second array

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like this perhaps (combination of filter and some)

```js
const first = [
  'decdbaf8-db89-4d4b-973a-e8edab55927c',
  'c553c2f7-eff6-476e-b718-2814a7fa5435',
  '8717092f-5820-474b-9dd9-165e2649180f'
];
const second = [{
    id: 'c553c2f7-eff6-476e-b718-2814a7fa5435',
    name: 'test',
    codReference: '15422aa',
    category_id: '7a026a80-f3d2-462a-ad5d-598e9eabf693',
    deleted_at: null
  },
  {
    id: 'decdbaf8-db89-4d4b-973a-e8edab55927c',
    name: 'test',
    codReference: '2',
    category_id: '7a026a80-f3d2-462a-ad5d-598e9eabf693',
    deleted_at: null
  }
]
const result = first.filter(x => !second.some(y => y.id === x));
console.log(result)
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use a filter. Here's a working solution:

```js
var arr1 = [
  'decdbaf8-db89-4d4b-973a-e8edab55927c',
  'c553c2f7-eff6-476e-b718-2814a7fa5435',
  '8717092f-5820-474b-9dd9-165e2649180f'
]


var arr2 = [
  {
    id: 'c553c2f7-eff6-476e-b718-2814a7fa5435',
    name: 'test',
    codReference: '15422aa',
    category_id: '7a026a80-f3d2-462a-ad5d-598e9eabf693',
    created_at: '2020-10-29T22:23:35.928Z',
    updated_at: '2020-10-29T22:23:35.928Z',
    deleted_at: null
  },
  {
    id: 'decdbaf8-db89-4d4b-973a-e8edab55927c',
    name: 'test',
    codReference: '2',
    category_id: '7a026a80-f3d2-462a-ad5d-598e9eabf693',
    created_at: '2020-10-29T22:23:37.784Z',
    updated_at: '2020-10-29T22:23:37.784Z',
    deleted_at: null
  }
]

var arr = arr2.map(_ => _.id);
var res = arr1.filter( function(n) { return !this.has(n) }, new Set(arr) );
console.log(res);
```

Comment: what is new Set(arr) ?

Comment: @GabrielCosta it's used to gid rid of duplicates :)

Comment: You should get rid of the edit which loops `arr2` inside `Set` - unnecesary and would slow down performance massively if `arr2` is of any considerable size. Otherwise this is preferrable solution since `Set` is hashed and can be looked up as opposed to iterated like the `some` solution above.